# Do I charge my first client before or after the design is complete?

Tags: business, client-relations, freelance, design-process

This is my first serious client and their first design experience. I am designing a Logo and a business card for them. We haven't discussed price yet and I haven't started on their design either, so **i'm wondering when I should charge them? Before I begin or after?**

Also, How should I charge them if it's the first design experience for the both of us? More specifically , **should I charge them based on the time it takes to design or a flat fee?**

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29355/how-to-use-value-based-pricing-for-design-projects nad http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/957/what-price-should-i-charge-for-design-services  and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18142/which-is-a-better-design-pricing-model searching these topics will also turn up other results.

Comment: You charge them any way you see fit and that you both agree upon and write it up in a contract. Typically, designers will request a down payment. This gives you some security and also gets the client invested in the process. As for hourly vs. flat fee, see the questions Scott links to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a first-time client, that you don't know and who doesn't know you, it is reasonable to request a down payment up front before any work is done which is a percentage of the total price for the project. You can request additional partial payment at pre-determined milestones along the way as well (such as delivery of first draft). Final files are not delivered (or rights/licenses granted) until after final and complete payment has been made.

All of this should be worked out before you do any work in your **written contract**.