# How much will it cost to create 3 completely different InDesign 24 pages Report Templates?

Tags: adobe-indesign, client-relations, business, template, pricing

My client asked for a quote to create 3 different  A4 InDesign templates with different page layouts, font families, colour palette, chapter separation styles, all the heading and paragraph styles set up with approx 24 pages layout. I have priced £490 for a 2 days work but the client thinks it is expensive.
Please advise as I don't want to work for free.

Comment: I'm afraid this question is impossible to answer as it depends on so many factors. You indirectly tell us you are in the UK by giving the price in pounds, but there are many details affecting the price we don't know about. In Denmark where I'm from, that price would be for about 1 full day's work - not 2.

Comment: Many prospective clients will **always** complain prices are too high. That doesn't mean they are. It means the "client" doesn't want to pay what you've quoted. How you negotiate from there is up to you. In my world, £490 ($682 US) would be **horribly, horribly** low for a 24p, A4 design - much less *three* of them, and *templates* to boot! But pricing is relative.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/25712/what-should-i-do-if-a-potential-client-claims-my-pricing-is-too-high